# How can I open downloaded java template in Maven?

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I got a homework to do and we have to use the premade java template. How can I open it as Maven project? I use intelliJ (mac) - prefer to open it through terminal command.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "premade java template"? Is this zip-File with a directory structure? Or an archetype?

Comment: its a zip-File with a directory structure

Comment: File - Open... - select the pom.xml file..

Comment: As suggested by @JB Nizet, to open a Maven project, just use File | Open action and point to the mail.pom.xml file to [import from](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start).